# Issue during pageload

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a rodiobuttongroup which should change the layout from vertical to horizontal when orientation is changed from portrait to landscape.
I am able to do that,but the only problem is I am not getting it during page load but when I am changing the orientation its reflecting.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
        if (mql.matches) {
            $("#id_cdscradiobtn").dxRadioGroup({
                items: CDSCRadioGroup,
                value: CDSCRadioGroup[0],
                layout: "vertical"
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#id_cdscradiobtn").dxRadioGroup({
                items: CDSCRadioGroup,
                value: CDSCRadioGroup[0],
                layout: "horizontal"
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to bind it to load **and** resize? Like this: `$(window).bind("load resize",function () {`

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the code into a common function that is called on both `resize` and DOM `ready` events:

```
function setLayouts() {
    var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
    if (mql.matches) {
        $("#id_cdscradiobtn").dxRadioGroup({
            items: CDSCRadioGroup,
            value: CDSCRadioGroup[0],
            layout: "vertical"
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#id_cdscradiobtn").dxRadioGroup({
            items: CDSCRadioGroup,
            value: CDSCRadioGroup[0],
            layout: "horizontal"
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setLayouts();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    setLayouts();
});
```